# Why doesn't this Block have copy and dispose pointers in its descriptor?

Tags: objective-c, compilation, objective-c-blocks

According to the `Block_private.h` file, whenever a block is declared in an Objective-c file, the following structures are created in the object file to represent it:

```
struct Block_descriptor {
    unsigned long int reserved;
    unsigned long int size;
    void (*copy)(void *dst, void *src);
    void (*dispose)(void *);
};

struct Block_layout {
    void *isa;
    int flags;
    int reserved; 
    void (*invoke)(void *, ...);
    struct Block_descriptor *descriptor;
    /* Imported variables. */
};
```

However, when I generate an assembly file, with `clang -S ...`, from

```
int(^squared)(int) = ^(int i) {
    return i*i;
};
```

I get the following snippet that represents the block:

```
    .type   .L.str210,@object       # @.str210
.L.str210:
    .asciz   "i12@?0i8"
    .size   .L.str210, 9

    .type   __block_descriptor_tmp,@object # @__block_descriptor_tmp
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
    .align  16
__block_descriptor_tmp:
    .quad   0                       # 0x0
    .quad   32                      # 0x20
    .quad   .L.str210
    .quad   0
    .size   __block_descriptor_tmp, 32

    .type   __block_literal_global,@object # @__block_literal_global
    .align  8
__block_literal_global:
    .quad   _NSConcreteGlobalBlock
    .long   1342177280              # 0x50000000
    .long   0                       # 0x0
    .quad   __main_block_invoke
    .quad   __block_descriptor_tmp
    .size   __block_literal_global, 32
```

So, `__block_literal_global` and `__block_descriptor_tmp` are a `Block_layout` and a `Block_descriptor`, respectively. But, as you can see, the third field of `__block_descriptor_tmp`, which should be a `void (*copy)(void *dst, void *src)` according to `Block_private.h`, is a `const char *` that points to the block's type encoding.

My question is: what does a block descriptor structure look like, exactly? Is my `Block_private.h` file deprecated, so that `Block_descriptor` implementation is currently different from the one I presented? If my file is right, why is the third field of `__block_descriptor_tmp` a `const char *`, not a `void (*copy)(void *dst, void *src)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The copy and dispose helpers are only included if the block has captures that need to be managed (Practically speaking: objects & __block vars)

If they are present then `block->flags & BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE`

Everything you need to know is outlined here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html

Comment: Oh, yes! So, in my case, the optional helper functions were not present, so that the third field of `__block_descriptor_tmp` corresponds to the signature field of `struct Block_descriptor_1` and the forth field is the end of the NULL-terminated array of imported variables. Since there is no imported variable, there is only a NULL at the end of `__block_descriptor_tmp`. Am I right?

Comment: The third field is the signature yes, but the NULL field is for garbage collection metadata, which is unused in the modern runtime. Captured vars are in the block_literal, not the descriptor (descriptor is shared amongst all instances of the block, while a new literal is allocated for each one)

Comment: Oh, of course. Sorry for the last part. I was crazy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

for     `.long   1342177280              # 0x50000000` means:

- Block->flags = 0x50000000

  - bit30=1 => `BLOCK_HAS_SIGNATURE`=1
  - bit28=1 => `BLOCK_IS_GLOBAL`=1

=>

- bit25=0 => `BLOCK_HAS_COPY_DISPOSE`=0

so:

- `this Block don't have copy and dispose pointers in its descriptor`
- this is a `Global` Block
- it has `signature`

---

- Appendix

  - [my ObjC Block tutorial](https://book.crifan.org/books/ios_re_objc_block/website/block_detail/block_layout/)

    - [Block definition figure](https://www.processon.com/view/link/6293498c0e3e74603c4b2039)

      - [image: block_layout_crifan_detail]